# Does Mathematica have an equivalent of Python's float.as_integer_ratio?

Tags: machine-precision, conversion, number-representation

The Python programming language has a `float.as_integer_ratio(x)` function which exactly converts an IEEE 754 floating-point number into a numerator/denominator pair of integers. For example:

```
float.as_integer_ratio(0.1)
 => (3602879701896397, 36028797018963968)
```

What is the *Mathematica* equivalent of this function for `MachinePrecision` numbers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`SetPrecision[]` does this:

```
SetPrecision[0.1, ∞]
   3602879701896397/36028797018963968
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks!

Comment: `SetAccuracy` appears to be equivalent. (+1)

Answer (score 11):

Not as clean as J.M.'s method but this seems to give the same result:

```
 0.1 ~RealDigits~ 2 ~FromDigits~ 2
```

> ```
> 3602879701896397/36028797018963968
> ```

Follow with [`Numerator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Numerator.html) and [`Denominator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Denominator.html) if needed.