# About the Rationalize of an approximated number

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

```
In[3]:= Clear["*"];
approPi = N[Pi];
{Rationalize[approPi], Round[approPi, 10^-15]}

Out[2]= {3.14159, 3141592653589793/1000000000000000}
```

Above `Rationalize` failed to give a rational number probably because that, [according to the Doc](https://wolfram.com/xid/0e7pxc5u-pus), there is no rational number "close enough" to `approPi`.
But apparently there exists a "close enough" rational number which is given by `Round`;

I know I can use `Rationalize[x,dx]` in this situation, according to the Doc:

> Rationalize[x,dx]:
>   yields the rational number with smallest denominator that lies within dx of x.

So below:

```
In[4]:= Clear["*"];
approPi = N[Pi];
{Rationalize[approPi, 0], Round[approPi, 10^-15]}
N[%, 20]

Out[2]= {245850922/78256779, 3141592653589793/1000000000000000}

Out[3]= {3.1415926535897931603, 3.1415926535897930000}
```

However, the error `dx` in the result `245850922/78256779` is by no means 0. Because `245850922/78256779`, ie `3.1415926535897931603...`, has the unnecessary `0.0000000000000001603` in it.

The result `3141592653589793/1000000000000000` of `Round` is the exact rational number equal to approPi. So I think the `3141592653589793/1000000000000000` I got via `Round` should be what `Rationalize[approPi, 0]` is supposed to output according to the Doc;

Comment: You might be looking for `SetPrecision[]` instead: `SetPrecision[N[π], ∞]`. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84234) as well.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for any way to convert an decimal fraction to rationals. I'm looking for an explanation rather then a way. An explanation about `Rationalize`'s strange behavior.  @J.M.

Comment: Then perhaps you should be comparing `ContinuedFraction[N[π]]` and `ContinuedFraction[Rationalize[N[π], 0]]`. Summary: `Rationalize[]`, `SetPrecision[]`, and `Round[]` all do quite different things.

Comment: @J.M.,  No. I need to know why the `Rationalize ` doesn't do what is said in the Doc. If the doc is wrong I need a clear definition of  `Rationalize `

Comment: @Bill I saw it, and how can you say that `3141592653589793/1000000000000000` isn't "close enough" to approPi? It's a strict equal, isn't it?

Comment: I was telling you what to look at so you could hopefully figure out an answer to your own question. Oh well, good luck with getting an answer!

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I've read your reference carefully and it's basically irrelevant to my topic.

Comment: Presumably, in the search for a "nearby rational with small denominator" it stops before it gets to denominators on the order of 10^15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under "Details" the documentation states:

> Rationalize[x,0] converts any inexact number x to rational form.

In fact, it yields a rational number that when converted back to approximate, is within the precision bounds of the approximate number, and often the difference is `0.`. This is reasonable and useful behavior.

```
Rationalize[N[Pi], 0] - N[Pi]
(* 0. *)
```

Comment: More precisely put: `Rationalize[]` works with the CF expansion of an inexact number, and returns the convergent whose difference with the input is less than or equal to the tolerance.

Comment: @J.M. So the reason why `Rationalize[]` failed to give a prefect matched rational number to target number is because it's lazy? Here I assume the target number is `approPi ` seen as an exact number, ie `3.141592653589793`. But dx specified here is 0, how is an inaccurate  result of `245850922/78256779`  given?

Comment: I already told you to look at the continued fraction, but you did not and thought it was irrelevant. I'll leave this to you to think about, @Murphy.

Comment: @MurphyNg (1) The exact fraction representing `approPi` internally is given by `SetPrecision[apprPi, Infinity]` -- it will have a denominator that is a power of `2` not `10`, since internally, floating-point is binary on (almost all) computers. (2) From the docs `Rationalize[x]` returns `p/q` such that `Abs[p/q - x] < 10^-4/q^2`, ***if*** such a `p/q` exists. And `Rationalize[x, 0]` is a special case that does what J.M. has indicated. It will usually return the same thing as `Rationalize[N[x], x*$MachineEpsilon/2]`, but there are edge cases that might be different.

Comment: This has been answered three times now (by John Doty, J.M., and Michael E2). The point is that the difference between rationalized result and inpu is 0 to all digits of precision. As for the "leftover" digits, that's an inevitable consequence of the fact that most binary numbers require more decimal digits to express than their precision warrants (stated differently, decimal-to-binary-to-decimal does not round-trip unless the input is exactly representable in both bases). I may vote to close this as a misunderstanding of the underlying math rather than a Mathematica issue per se.

Comment: So `Rationalize[N[Pi], 0] - N[Pi]==0`, which apparently satisfy the "close enough" definition of `Abs[p/q - x] < 10^-4/q^2`. Then, why doesn't `Rationalize[N[Pi]]` return the same result as  `Rationalize[N[Pi], 0] ` do?

Comment: @MichaelE2 About "The exact fraction representing approPi internally is given by SetPrecision[apprPi, Infinity]", there is something I feel inconsistent. Or can you please check out [my another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223509/72284)?

Comment: @MurphyNg You're right. I didn't realize (or forgot) it rounded off the denominator to the nearest power of 2 that can represent the `Accuracy[]` of the number. You have to extend the accuracy, before setting the precision to infinity. I haven't tracked down the precise extra precision, but this seems sufficient to get a stable result (stable in that increasing the 30 does not change results): `SetPrecision[SetPrecision[x, Precision[x]+30], Infinity]`